# WordPress functions not working

Tags: php, wordpress, function, html

I'm trying to customize a HTML5 Boilerplate WordPress theme to develop my own theme, but I can't get any functions to work: my index.php file starts with

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html <?php language_attributes(); ?> class="no-js ie6"> <![endif]-->
```

But when I view source, the document ends with `<html`. It doesn't generate a fatal error ("`Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_header() in /home/micha162/public_html/index.php on line 1`"), as it would  on a server without WordPress installed. I've included all the required WordPress files and I can log into wp-admin just fine. I'm storing it on a subfolder but I've redirected the Site Address to the root folder, where index.php and header.php are installed. What could be going wrong?

Comment: Temporarily remove `<?php language_attributes(); ?>` and see if you still get the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to install wordpress themes into the theme directory, not the root directory.

The theme directory is: `/wp-content/themes`.